# What Typo3 version works for MySQL 8

Tags: typo3, mysql-8.0

In the requirement list of Typo3, it is always mentioned to use MySQL 5.5 til 5.7.
My customer only supports Mysql 8.
Has anyone experienced using Typo3 with Mysql 8? Does any Typo3 version work with Mysql 8?

Answer (score 2):

We're running MySQL 8 without problems, using TYPO3 v9+ this shouldn't be a problem. However, we're running TYPO3 in composer mode, so we can fetch the latest Doctrine DBAL dependency (2.10+) without problems and with proper support.

Answer (score 2):

This mainly depends on the TYPO3 major version e.g. [TYPO3 10.4](https://get.typo3.org/version/10#system-requirements) and higher do support MySql 8 while lowers do not or partially only.

The system requirements are actively maintained at the TYPO3 download portal at https://get.typo3.org.

Comment: Thanx for this info. Then i have to update to Typo3 10.4